# handling a few elements with one event listner javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, foreach, addeventlistener

I am new to JavaScript, and I am making a project by following the tutorial video.

I can not understand the part of adding eventlisntner to a few elements. 
This below code is when keydown is happening, .playing from css is going to add to key variable.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data key="${e.keyCode}"]`)
if(!audio){
  return;
}

const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`)
audio.currentTime = 0;//rew ind to the start
audio.play();
key.classList.add('playing');


})
```

and this is the code of removing the css style from them, and it will work right away when above code works.

```
function removeTransition(e){
    if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;//skip if its transform
    this.classList.remove('playing')

}


const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');  
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
```

but when I remove .playing from HTML, why do I have to add forEach to addEventListner? The instructor was saying I need to specify which key, but I wonder then why the first code is working without forEach even though it has a few elements.

this  is .playing in css

```
.playing {
transform: scale(1.1);
border-color: #ffc600;
box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600;
}
```

I hope you guys could solve this question, thank you so much.

Comment: `document.querySelector` returns a single element (the first match to the selector) ... `document.querySelectorAll` returns multiple elements, you can't add an event listener to a NodeList - you iterate through the nodelist and add event listeners to each element in the list

Comment: Oh I see, I knew the difference of them but I was not sure how addEventListener going to work to them, you solved my problem, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is familiar, is it the Drum Kit project from Wes? xD

Alright. First you add playing class to any key if it's pressed, the class plays a transition on a key (which is a button on GUI). For the forEach() part it waits for the transition (played by playing class) to end, after that it will remove the class from all the buttons so you can add it back when a key is pressed again. If you add a class to an element without removing it, the element will only take effect once , if you press a key again nothing will happen to the button. It's because classList.add() method will add a class to an element if and only if that class is not inside the element yet.

Hope I don't confuse you even more.

Comment: Yea exactly! but some code suffer me from understanding! Thank you for answering!